# Error al tratar de crear una tabla de sqlite a partir de una clase que obtengo de un JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net, xamarin.forms

Actualmente tengo un json en un servidor que descargo y lo plasmo en una clase de C# y quiero que el modelo de esa clase cree una tabla en sqlite para que ahi se almacene la informacion de mi json

Codigo:

```
 db.CreateTableAsync<clase_principal>().Wait();
```

Clase:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using xxxxxxxxx.Models;

namespace xxxxxxxxxxx.Models
{



    public  class clase_principal
    {

        public int id = 0;

        [JsonProperty("casos")]
        public Casos Casos { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("listado")]
        public Dictionary<string, Listado[]> Listado { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("estatusActividades")]
        public EstatusActividades EstatusActividades { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("faq")]
        public Faq Faq { get; set; }
    }

    public class Casos
    {
        [JsonProperty("descartados")]
        public long Descartados { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("investigacion")]
        public long Investigacion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("confirmados")]
        public long Confirmados { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("comunitaria")]
        public long Comunitaria { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recuperados")]
        public long Recuperados { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fallecidos")]
        public long Fallecidos { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fase")]
        public string Fase { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class EstatusActividades
    {
        [JsonProperty("Actividades laborales")]
        public Actividades ActividadesLaborales { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Actividades escolares")]
        public Actividades ActividadesEscolares { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Actividades
    {
        [JsonProperty("estatus")]
        public string Estatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("contenido")]
        public string Contenido { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Faq
    {
        [JsonProperty("Salud")]
        public Escolare[] Salud { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Escolares")]
        public Escolare[] Escolares { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Escolare
    {
        [JsonProperty("pregunta")]
        public string Pregunta { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("respuesta")]
        public string Respuesta { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Listado
    {
        [JsonProperty("confirmados", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long? Confirmados { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("descartados", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long? Descartados { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("investigacion", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long? Investigacion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long? Id { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Y me marca el siguiente error:

One or more errors occurred. (Don't know about App_Covid.Models.Casos)

Comment: veo que tenes clases parciales y otras que no? te fijaste de cambiarla? y por otro lado, asi de crea las clases cuando hacer convertis el json a c# porque el visual te crear las clases solas si pegas como json.